# Setting session_replication_role for GCP Cloud SQL

Tags: google-cloud-sql, postgresql-9.6

I am trying to run `SET session_replication_role = 'replica';` in a GCP Cloud SQL Postgres 9.6 instance, however I'm encountering this error `ERROR:  permission denied to set parameter "session_replication_role"` even if the  postgres user is a cloudsql admin user. Do I have to spin up my own self managed instance to solve the problem or is there a way around it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not connected with the service is in Beta or not, you can't set **session_replication_role** in GCP Cloud SQL.

You need to have [superuser privileges to do that operation](https://web.archive.org/web/20210410150147/https://www.endpoint.com/blog/2012/10/25/postgres-system-triggers-error), but GCP Cloud only allows to *cloudsqlsuperuser* privileges. It's [features as follows](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/users):

> When you create a new Cloud SQL for PostgreSQL instance, the default postgres user is already created for you, though you must set its password.
>
> The postgres user is part of the cloudsqlsuperuser role, and has the following attributes (privileges): CREATEROLE, CREATEDB, and LOGIN. **It does not have the SUPERUSER or REPLICATION attributes.**

You can find much more information in [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20210410150147/https://www.endpoint.com/blog/2012/10/25/postgres-system-triggers-error) blog post.

Comment: Here is an archived copy of the broken link/blog post. https://web.archive.org/web/20210410150147/https://www.endpoint.com/blog/2012/10/25/postgres-system-triggers-error

Perhaps someone can put the relevant information into the comments, or into the Answer.

Comment: @weezilla thanks for pointing out the broken link. It's updated now!

Answer (score 3):

We also encountered same issue . This is because postgres user does not have `Replication` permission.

To resolve this issue:

a) Login with postgres user

b) Since postgres user has `Create role` permission. Now create a new user with below command:

`CREATE USER <YOUR_USER> WITH PASSWORD '<YOUR_PASSWORD>' CREATEDB CREATEROLE REPLICATION IN GROUP cloudsqlsuperuser;`

replace *<YOUR_USER>* with your user name and *<YOUR_PASSWORD>* with password.

c)  Login with newly created user and run

`SET session_replication_role = 'replica';`

if you see response `SET` then you are good to go

Comment: Also don't forget to grant permission to the new user.
`GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO <YOUR_USER>`
`GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO <YOUR_USER>;`

Answer (score 2):

From what I was looking at, since the service is currently in Beta, there are still some features that are not available, such as that. Therefore we would need to wait a bit more for Google to realease the final version of their product.