# disable trigger on table on GCP

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, triggers

I'm doing DB migration and I would need to disable the foreign key constraints on a table in order to migrate peacefully.

From this: [How do I temporarily disable triggers in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942258/how-do-i-temporarily-disable-triggers-in-postgresql)

I've gathered that I would need superuser permissions to run:

```
SET session_replication_role = replica;
```

and

```
SET session_replication_role = DEFAULT;
```

However; on google cloud platform it is impossible to get those privileges as detailed in the docs:

> The postgres user is part of the cloudsqlsuperuser role and has the following attributes (privileges): CREATEROLE, CREATEDB, and LOGIN. It does not have the SUPERUSER or REPLICATION attributes

and to this StackOverflow question: [upgrade user to superuser in postgres google cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48442200/upgrade-user-to-superuser-in-postgres-google-cloud)

I also tried to disable triggers via:

```
alter table orders.orders disable trigger all;
```

However; for this it seems to me, that I also need su rights:
`ERROR:  permission denied: "RI_ConstraintTrigger_a_25017" is a system trigger`

So then, what is the solution, can I even disable triggers // foreign key constraints on this particular table or not?

Comment: You can create a new user to superuser role.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73080002/4380384

Answer (score 4):

Like you have read from the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/users#superuser_restrictions), these commands require `superuser` privileges, which are not available to users in CloudSQL yet.

> Because Cloud SQL for PostgreSQL is a managed service, it restricts access to certain system procedures and tables that require advanced privileges.

There is actually an open [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/196607815) focusing on this feature. It does not seem to have an ETA yet as per the available info. Regardless, it appears that there are replication services which do not require `superuser`, as this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53108828/) says. Otherwise, GCP also offers the [Data Migration Service](https://cloud.google.com/database-migration/docs/postgres/faq), which, according to the documentation, supports migrating foreign key constraints for PostgreSQL instances.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't need superuser to issue

```
SET session_replication_role = replica;
SET session_replication_role = default;
```

you just need REPLICATION  ( I just tested it )

```
ALTER ROLE <your user> REPLICATION;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get superuser privilege but you can gain some of the superuser privileges by setting the right database flags.

Quoting from the documentation: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/flags#session_replication_role

> session_replication_role
> PostgreSQL has a session_replication_role flag which is designed to be used for logical replication and which allows disabling constraint triggers in individual sessions.
>
> Sometimes this flag can also be used for some maintenance operations
> to circumvent constraint (most often Foreign Key) checks.
>
> This flag can be set in a session by any user which has the REPLICATION property set. The REPLICATION property for any user can be set by cloudsqlsuperuser when one of flags cloudsql.enable_pglogical or cloudsql.logical_decoding is set for the instance.

How you can set a flag in your database is very easy and explained here: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/flags#set_a_database_flag for all cases (console, gcloud, terraform and etc)

### What worked for me

I have found the above solution while trying to solve the very same problem. However, as @Paolo Castelletti said,

```
ALTER ROLE <your user> REPLICATION;
```

was actually enough for me to apply

```
SET session_replication_role = replica;
```

I wanted to share the other approach as well in case it helps someone